# R won't start with Mac Os Sierra v10.12.4

Tags: r, macos

When I click on the RStudio button in my Mac application folder, I have the following error message:

"Unable to locate R binary by scanning standard locations"

I am using macOs Sierra v10.12.4 and RStudio-1.0.143.dmg file from rstudio.com and I really don't know what to do. Could someone please help me on this?

Best, paul

Comment: Did you install R first? RStudio does not include R. You can download R for macOS here, https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: @ beigel, TY man! It works ^^